# @ApiProperty openapi_context type array example

Tags: php, annotations, openapi, api-platform.com

Is it possible to create openapi_context "type"="array" for @ApiProperty? What is the correct way to write "example" value of sucha array using annotations? I am using OAS3

```
/**
 * @ApiProperty(
 *     attributes={
 *      "openapi_context"={
 *        "type"="array",
 *        "example"="array example goes here"
 *      }
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @var array<array>
 */
```

EDIT:

expected output (that works when I enter it to Request body in SwaggerUI) is

```
    "my_array": {
      "key" : {
        "key1" : "value 1",
        "key2" : "value 2",
        "key3" : "value 3"
       }
     }
```

there are no square brackets there

Answer (score 3):

*I'm not sure to understand your question, because I don't know the content of your array. Feel free to add a comment if this is not answering your question.*

**The array type**

The primitive data types defined by the [OpenApi Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md) are documented in [this chapter](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#data-types). There is no mention about array, certainly because this is not a primitive data type.

Because, if you look at the [schema 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/schemas/v3.0/schema.yaml), [Line 203](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/schemas/v3.0/schema.yaml#L203) description of schema begins. Arrays ([Line 263](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/schemas/v3.0/schema.yaml#L263)) are accepted. 
So, yes it is possible to create openapi_context "type"="array" for @ApiProperty

**The examples**
And if you look at the [schema 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/schemas/v3.0/schema.yaml), Example ([Line 323](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/schemas/v3.0/schema.yaml#L323)) are object without specification. So you can write what you want. I'm not a big fan, and a lot of documentation use example to provide an accepted value.

So, I use Swagger which respect the OAS3. Array are [documented](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array) and you can find some example in comments. Somme example are defined in "comments". These examples come from Swagger documentation.

- Example of an array of integer `"[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]"`
- Example of an array of object  `"[ {"id": 5}, {"id": 8} ]"`
- Example of an array of array of integer `"[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]"`
- etc.

For a multidimensional array, this is the swagger context:

```yaml
    # [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]
    type: array
    items:
      type: array
      items:
        type: integer
```

The annotation is:

```php
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(
     *     attributes={
     *      "openapi_context"={
     *        "type"="array",
     *        "items" = {"type"="array", "items"={"type"={"integer","string"}}},
     *        "example"="[[1,'foo'], ['bar',4, 5]]"
     *      }
     *     }
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
```

I have create an entity with a property which is a multidimensional array which contains string or integer. (array of array of (string or integer)) and I take screenshot of the swagger documentation. It seems to be fine!

The result of the sample is:

[image: Sample screenshot]

The generated schema is:

[image: Schema screenshot]

[The example are well documented](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array), you could find answer for your array.

Comment: Hi @alexandre-tranchant thank you for your response. I want to define an example of multidimensional associative array and I want to di it specifically in annotation, I somehow can't find what is the right syntax to build this example in annotation.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the syntax example. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @alexandre-trenchant whe I use your example I am getting 400Error: Bad Request "hydra:description": "The type of the \"templateVariables\" attribute must be \"array\", \"string\" given.",

Comment: of course templateVariables is the name of my property

Comment: Your expected value isn't an array, but an object.

Comment: My ApiResource is a POPO not a Doctrine Entity, this model has a property declared as private array $templateVariables = []; it has a docblock @var array<array> my "openapi_context"={  "type"="array"}, SwaggerUI displays example as  "templateVariables": [ "string" ] BUT I want multidimensional associative array so this won't work with square brackets I have to use curly ones right?  so this does not mean that I expect an object its just the JSON syntax that for this requires curly brackets isn't it?  JSON won't accept {"key" : ["key1" : "value1"]} it needs to be {"key" : {"key1" : "value1"}}